# Excel Pivot (Consolidate data based on the open and closed date)

Tags: excel, vba

- Image one is the source data
- Image two is the required output

we have 4 date columns(created year/month. closed year/month). The tricky part in the output is the closed count.

In the output, the columns(year,Month) are based on (created year/month) so when i pivot the source data value the closed ticket count should be based on the columns(closed year/month).

Thanks In Advance

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that kind of calculation with a pivot table. But you can use a regular table and Countifs to get the result you describe.

[image]

The formula in D17 is

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Created Year],B17,Table1[Created Month],C17)
```

In E17

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[status],"closed",Table1[Closed Year],B17,Table1[closed month],C17)
```

Copy down